# How to move a table down when the window is resized

Tags: html, css

**Scenario :**

- I have two tables that are next to each other.

**Todo :**

- I would like to know how to move the right table down when the window
  is resized. The table should be able to resize with the table also.

It would be great if someone could help me out with the css.
[Click here for link to codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PyvWma#anon-signup)

```
.leftContainer {
    width:50%;
position:fixed;
top:45%;
//display:inline-flex;

table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
td {
    border:none;
}
thead {
    background-color: #002559;
    color: white
}
tbody {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    td {
        padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    }
}
}
.rightContainer {
    max-width: 50vw;
    position:fixed;
    //float:right;
    top:45%;
    right:5%;
display:flex;

table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
td {
    border:none;
}
thead {
    background-color: #002559;
    color: white
}
tbody {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    td {
        padding: 10px;
    }
}
}
```

[image: DISPLAY OF TABLES]

Comment: please add some demo for the problem.

Comment: Add your table html please, also if its nested in a div, add that whole html code.

Comment: why would you fix the position and expect it to fall? Any thing in html that do not have space to fit in will tend to fall.

Comment: You can do it with simple @media, but you need to show us the html to answer it correctly.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Hey. I have added a link for the demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that both the containers are having fixed position. 
So if both containers can be given relative position in your case, then with flex box we can achieve the following.

**Approach :**

- Provide display flex to body (the container of both the divs)
- Allow flex-wrap so that the other div can be adjusted accordingly by getting below the first div if enough space is not present.

  > Let me know in comments, if its not helpful. See in **full page mode**

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.leftContainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
 width:50%;
 position:relative;
}

 table, th, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 th {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
 }
 td {
  border:none;
 }
 thead {
  background-color: #002559;
  color: white
 }
 tbody {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  td {
   padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
  }
 }
}
.rightContainer {
  border: 1px black solid;
 max-width: 50vw;
 position:leative;
 flex:wrap;
 //float:right;
 top:45%;
 right:5%;
 display:flex;

 table, th, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 th {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
 }
 td {
  border:none;
 }
 thead {
  background-color: #002559;
  color: white
 }
 tbody {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  td {
   padding: 10px;
  }
 }
}
.unreadMsgDiv{
 height:18px;
 width:18px !important;
 border-radius:10px;
 background-color:#FFA200;
 display:inline-block !important;
 font-size:13px;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin-left: 15px;
 color: black;
 border: 1px solid #FFA200;
}

.beforeRead {
 background-color: #FFA200;
 padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.afterRead {
 background-color: #BFBFBF;
 padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.status {
 background-color:white;
 border: 1.2px solid #AEAEAE;
 width:100px !important; 
 height:100px !important;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.statusTop {
 margin: 20px 0px 5px 0px;
 font-size: 30px;
 display: block;
}
.statusBottom {
 font-size: 12px;
}
.status:hover {
 background-color:#002559;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
       <div class="leftContainer">
        <table>
         <thead>
          <th colspan="4" style="text-align:left">Overview</th>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td><div class="status"><span class="statusTop">10</span><span class="statusBottom" >Total cases</span></div></td>
           <td><div class="status"><span class="statusTop">5</span><span class="statusBottom"><router-link style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" :to="{ name: 'Applications', params: { appType: 'pending', test: 'testinggg' }}">PENDING</router-link></span></div></td>
           <td><div class="status"><span class="statusTop">3</span><span class="statusBottom">SUCCESSFUL</span></div></td>
           <td><div class="status"><span class="statusTop">2</span><span class="statusBottom">REJECTED</span></div></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
       </div>

       <div class="rightContainer">
        <table>
         <thead>
          <th colspan="3" style="text-align:left">Updates<div class="unreadMsgDiv">unreadMsg</div></th>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td style="font-style:italic; font-size:13px; padding-bottom: 15px;" colspan="3">10 new updates since last login on...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td><span>30 Sept</span></td>
           <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Ref. 1234454</td>
           <td>Supervisor has approved the details. Please do check.</td>           
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
       </div>
```

Comment: Hi, @abhishek I am really sorry. But this did not work well with my content. The right content would still overlap the left content.

Comment: @JaslinKaur please check again, now the right container comes just beneath the first div if no extra space is available for right container.

Comment: @JaslinKaur any component should be given a position if you want to change its position, by default they get default positioning. For your left div, you are explicitly providing 50% width so, the right container will start after 50%. But, on resize if no space is left for right container, it will move itself down under first container.

Comment: @JaslinKaur please upvote the answer as its helpful, as upvoting is good for the people who look for answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
.leftContainer, .rightContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-basis: auto;
    max-width: 50%;
    align-content: baseline;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th {
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    }
    td {
        border: none;
    }
    thead {
        background-color: #002559;
        color: white
    }
    tbody {
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
    }
}

.leftContainer {
    td {
        padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    }
}

.rightContainer {
    td {
        padding: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: rest of it you can add in media queries controlling the max-width